# Replace function not supporting for bigger text and text has single quote

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

this is the statement execute from SNowflake SP.

var sql_Statement = "select regexp_replace ('" + mainSIDColsSrc + "'', 'source_doc:','') " ;

form the query like this :
select regexp_replace ('(trim(NVL(SOURCE_DOC:claimNumber::string,'~')) ||'^'|| trim(NVL(SOURCE_DOC:notificationType::string,'~')) ||'^'|| trim(NVL(SOURCE_DOC:estimateId::string,'~')) ||'^'|| trim(NVL(SOURCE_DOC:assignmentId::string,'~')))'', 'source_doc:','')

if run the above query :
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 82 unexpected '~'. syntax error line 1 at position 153 unexpected '~'. syntax error line 1 at position 305 unexpected ':'. parse error line 1 at position 311 near ''.

Comment: Does this environment have 'placeholders' or 'parameters'? This sort of error is almost always an issue with not using parameterized queries.

Comment: Perhaps useful: https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/